# Grothendieck-Lefschetz fixed point theorem for nonconstant sheaves?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety over ${\bf F}_q$. The Grothendieck-Lefschetz fixed point formula gives
$$|X({\bf F}_q)|=\sum_i(-1)^i\text{Tr}(\text{Frob},H^i_c(X,\bf{Q}_\ell))$$
for the constant $\ell$-adic sheaf on $X$.

More generally but are there local systems/constructible sheaves on $X$ such that the point counting on the LHS still remain valid?

Comment: Probably it is not what you are looking for, but for an arbitrary constructible sheaf the formula remains valid after replacing the LHS by the sum of Frobenius traces on stalks over $\mathbb{F}_q$-points, see SGA 4.5, Expose 2

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at SGA and wondering if there is a nonconstant sheaf F such that Tr(Frob_x, F) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatley I have not enough reputation to add a comment, but you could look at the case $X(\mathbb{F}_q) = \emptyset$ which shows you that such sheaves might exist. Perhaps you should allow $q$ to vary?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the case where there is no ${\bf F}_q$ point, should the trace of Frobenius be 1 or 0? On the other hand, I am thinking about a skyscraper sheaf, say ${\bf Q}_{\ell\{0\}}$, maybe this is works?

Comment: The trace does not matter as the sum on the left hand side is empty, i.e. always 0. So the formula remains valid for all constructible sheaves

Comment: That is true when there is no rational point, but this is a somewhat vacuous example. For the skyscraper sheaf I am asking for at some rational points.

Comment: Yes, if you use the sum of the skyscraper sheaves at all rational points it would work. My point was meant to be rather a "there are not many rational points, so you are not asking for many conditions"-argument - there should be many such sheaves, as you are only asking for one equality, which might even be vacuous.  You could also look at a skyscraper sheaf on only one point where the Frobenius-action has trace equal to your number of rational points, or you could look at some higher-dimensional local systems given by $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ representation generated by a trace $1$-matrix etc